trying to reference values of a range using cells
I am trying to set the values of cells in a range in the current worksheet

to be the values of an equivalent range from another worksheet
using .range(cells... since the range size is variable

This works perfectly:
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range("A2:A22").Value

This fills all cells in the range with the value of the first cell in the reference range:
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Cells(2, "A").Value

But these do not work:
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(22, "A")).Value
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value

I get

Run-time error 1004
Application-defined or object defined error

I am a little stumped and could do with some help please


It is important to qualify the Range object with Sheet object.

Below code works well.


Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range("A2:A22").Value


But this doesn't. Staff list isn't the ActiveSheet. Cells(22, "A") is equalient to ActiveSheet.Cells(22, "A"). That's the reason why it raises 1004.

Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(22, "A")).Value


Pls try.

Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")  ' modify as needed, change Sheet1 to ActiveSheet.Name
Set oSht2 = Sheets("Staff list")
With oSht1
    .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = oSht2.Range(oSht2.Cells(2, "A"), oSht2.Cells(22, "A")).Value
End With


There are several options to simplify the code.


With oSht1
    .Cells(2, "A").Resize(ListSize - 1).Value = oSht2.Cells(2, "A").Resize(ListSize - 1).Value
End With

With oSht1
    .Range("A2:A" & ListSize).Value = oSht2.Range("A2:A" & ListSize).Value
End With

With oSht1.Range("A2:A" & ListSize)
    .Value = oSht2.Range(.Address(0, 0)).Value
End With


Copy Single Column Values
Sub CopySingleColumn()
    ' Avoid long unreadable lines with loads of repetitions.
    ' Use variables instead. Also, consider using the With statement.
    ' If you have decided to change your sheet name to e.g. 'Staff',
    ' you'll have to change it only in one place in this code.
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source:
    ' Qualify the sheet with the workbook and the range with the sheet
    ' i.e. 'wb.Sheets(...)' and 'sws.Range(...)' respectively.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Staff list")
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("A2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    
    ' Destination:
    ' Specify the sheet whenever possible. Keep in mind that the active
    ' sheet could be in the wrong workbook.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A2").Resize(srg.Rows.Count) ' !!!
    
    ' Copy values.
    drg.Value = srg.Value

End Sub


I referenced the worksheet within the range function for each cells and it fixed it:
Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")).Value = Worksheets("Staff list").Range(Worksheets("Staff list").Cells(2, "A"), Worksheets("Staff list").Cells(22, "A")).Value


Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(ListSize, "A")) isn't reliable because it depends on the ActiveSheet.

In addition to @taller's comment: Be explicit and fully qualify all your range references, e.g. via ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range(...) or by prefixing a worksheet's unique CodeName associated to your VBA project (as listed in the VB Editor's project explorer, c.f. property window (Name) as opposed to the tabular Name) like e.g. Sheet1.Range(...)
